# SELECT Syntax Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I execute this statement, I get a syntax error near ''.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DBName].[SName].[ProjectMemberRelations] pmr 
  INNER JOIN  DBName.SName.Person as p 
    ON pmr.PersonId = p.Id AND p.LoginId = 'some login id' 
WHERE pmr.ProjectId = ﻿1
```

When I remove `WHERE pmr.ProjectId = ﻿1` clause I get no more errors. But, of course, I can't remove it because I need it filtered on ProjectId 1.

Thanks

Comment: where and how do you execute this query ?

Comment: Does the `some login id` value include an apostrophe (')?

Comment: No, there are no apostrophes.

Comment: The sql is executed in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Just as an aside, the `AND p.LoginId = 'some login id'` part of your INNER JOIN could be moved into the WHERE clause, like so: `WHERE pmr.ProjectId = 1 AND p.LoginId = 'some login id'`

Comment: And you're sure you've got a `ProjectId` column in ProjectMemberRelations ? No typo ? Could you give the entire error message ?

Comment: As Boas Enkler stated, I retyped the WHERE clause instead of copy and paste, and the query worked. I assume that there was some invisible char in there.

Comment: It's your number 1, it's not actually a 1 it's something else and SQL server doesn't like it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of LoginId; Does it have illegal characters ?

s. [MSDN - Invalid Characters and Escape Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx)
Also make sure that you don't have any, perhaps invisible, special chars in the text of your query

For Example try to send it via management studio by retyping it ( no copy and paste)

Comment: I will accept this as the answer. When I retyped the WHERE clause and executed, the query worked! Thanks.

Comment: looks like invalid special char, a year ago i had that issue and searched for hours.

Comment: The retyping it part is a valid point, however I am not sure how  invalid XML characters are handled by the `FOR XML` clause is relevant...

Comment: @BoasEnkler just as an aside, you mention searching for hours, did you know if you double click the error message in SSMS (Incorrect syntax near ''.) it will highlight the line containing the invalid character for you?

Comment: Yeah but in these days i used an very old IDE (FoxPro) that didn't support this. But useful comment ! (upvoted)